# Comunicação entre forms

Tags: winforms

Olá. Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação que deverá funcionar da seguinte forma:
Ao ser executada, um form principal (Form1) deverá abrir e ficar sempre de fundo.
Este form principal contém opções para o usuário realizar suas escolhas através de um botão com o texto "adicionar". Quando o usuário clicar no botão "adicionar" deverá abrir outro form (Form2) em que o usuário deverá colocar suas informações em textbox e depois clicar em um botão com o texto "salvar". Ao clicar no botão "salvar" o Form2 deverá ser fechado. O form principal deverá ficar sempre aberto no fundo. O usuário terá outras opções no form principal que ele poderá escolher para preencher através de outros forms (Form3, Form4...Formn) e sempre que clicar em "salvar" nos forms os mesmos serão fechados permanecendo somente o Form1.

No Form1 terá um botão "gerar relatório" que ao ser clicado deverá exportar todos os dados salvos nos outros forms para uma planilha Excel.

Já construí a aplicação com todos os Forms e o código para gerar o relatório.

A pergunta é: Como faço para enviar os dados de outros forms para o Form1 sendo que os mesmos estarão fechados ou serão fechado quando o usuário clicar em "salvar" ??

Já tentei várias alternativas de comunicação entre forms mas sem sucesso. Verifiquei todas as opções só funcionam se eu de um comando .show() e abrir
o form principal novamente...mas na minha aplicação isto não poderá ser feito...

Como faço para salvar os dados sem ter que abrir forms novamente...??

Comment: Confusa a sua questão, até sei a resposta de comunicação entre form mas, os forms auxiliares (form2, form3 etc), manda exatamente qual atualização para o form principal?

Comment: Os forms 2, 3, 4...n terão textbox onde o usuário colocará as informações de quantidade, código do produto, posição de instalação enfim, coisas inerentes ao projeto...Ao preencher os dados nos form2, 3, 4...n o usuário    deverá clicar em um botão que salva estas informações e fecha o form2, 3, 4...ou n...ficando somente o form1 que estava de fundo (maximizado). O Form1 tem um botão "gerar relatório" que exporta todas os dados preenchidos nos forms2, 3, 4...n para uma tabela excel...

Comment: Porém, nos teste que eu fiz, eu só consegui gerar a tabela no excel com os dados, se ao clicar nos botões salvar dos forms2, 3, 4...n eu abrir novamente o Form1 (que já estava aberto...de fundo)...caso contrário eu não consigo transferir os dados dos textbox dos forms2, 3, 4...n para algum vetor, memória...etc...

Comment: Parece que a atualização só ocorre no momento em que o form é executado (aberto)...

Comment: coloque o código de abertura de um item e o que no form1 precisa ficar com os valores dos outros forms!

Comment: Realmente a sua pergunta está meio confusa, mas aparentemente a única forma de você manter os dados e usá-los em Forms diferentes seria usando banco de dados. Att. Flávio.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar informações entre forms do C#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166563/passar-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-entre-forms-do-c)

Comment: Olá, pode criar variáveis globais. Assim uma variável criada no form 1 pode ser mudada a partir de outros forms.

Answer (score 0):

Quando for abrir outro form, passe como parâmetro o `form1` para poder acessar um método dentro dele para poder guardar as informações retornadas do outro form.

**EXEMPLO FORM 1:**

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(this); //passe como parâmetro este form1.
}

public void SalvarDadosForm2(string dado1, string dado2, string dado3)
{
    //Salve os dados em variáveis ou outra forma que desejar, 
    //Pode criar um método único ou um para cada form, você quem sabe o melhor jeito.
}
```

**EXEMPLO DEMAIS FORMS**

No construtor dos demais forms aplique:

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{
    Form1 form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.form1 = form1;
    }
    // Outras linhas de código, não interessantes ao exemplo.
}
```

Então realize tudo o que precisa fazer e no método onde termina a validação dos dados dos demais forms, inclua:

```
   form1.Show();

   form1.SalvarDadosForm2(textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text); //Envia as informações para o form1

   form1.Focus();

   this.Close();
```

Comment: Então, se eu coloco form1.Show(); aí funciona, porém a tela que está no fundo maximizada será aberta novamente...e é isto que eu não posso ter em minha aplicação. Sem colocar o form1.Show(); aí as variáveis não são   atualizadas...tentei criar uma classe específica para salvar os valores inseridos nos textbox, para depois chamar estas variáveis a partir do form1, mas também não deu certo...

Comment: vou testar form1.Refresh();