# Passar informações entre forms do C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá,

Estou com um problema pra passar informações entre formulários windows forms com C#, o problema é o seguinte. Eu tenho um FORM PRINCIPAL, a partir deste, eu chamo o um SUB FORM, que passa a ser filho do principal. A questão é que, eu quero que, o SUB FORM me passe, ou retorne uma informação de volta para o PRINCIPAL. Pode ser um valor booleano, lista, enfim, quero passar qualquer valor.

Exemplo:

NO FORM PRINCIPAL:

```
private void buttonDiretorio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form Frm = new FormOpenDirectorySystem();
        Frm.ShowDialog();
        bypass = Frm.bypass;

        if (bypass)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O acesso foi concedido.", "Acesso liberado.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (Directory.Exists("C:\\Diretorio\\"))
            {
                //abro o diretório
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("O diretório raiz do sistema não foi encontrado.", "Problema ao abrir o diretório raiz", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

NO SUB FORMULÁRIO QUE É CHAMADO PELO FORM PRINCIPAL:

```
public partial class FormOpenDirectorySystem : Form
{
    public FormOpenDirectorySystem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool bypass = false;

    private void buttonCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bypass = false;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void buttonContinuar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String password = txtBypass.Text;
        if (password == "1q2w3e4r5t")
        {
            bypass = true;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            bypass = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Nesse meu exemplo, eu estou no form principal, e chamo uma nova tela, onde eu vou fazer a leitura de uma senha/password/bypass, e quero que esse bypass me retorne VERDADEIRO, se a "autenticação" foi bem sucedida, ou FALSO se não foi bem sucedido.

Atenciosamente;

Comment: Provavelmnete alguma dessa desse ser o que deseja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+entre+forms

Comment: @bigown Eu estava mesmo procurando um dup pra essa, mas parece que todas querem fazer o caminho contrário.

Comment: João, eu escrevi uma resposta e agora me dei me conta que você faz **exatamente isso** no código da pergunta! Qual é o problema com o código atual?

Comment: o problema é exatamente que não funciona, kk Qual seria o erro no código, porque eu estou tentando com esse método e simplesmente não tenho retorno de nada.

Comment: Não funciona como? **Seja mais claro!** O que acontece? Dá algum erro? O retorno é sempre o mesmo?

Comment: Bom,. no código de exemplo eu tento acessar a propriedade do meu SUB FORM, frm.bypass, e passo ela para bypass , no meu form principal.

Comment: Acontece que no form principal, eu tenho o erro de que não existe propriedade "bypass" em "frm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com uma propriedade pública no form secundário

```
public partial class FormOpenDirectorySystem : Form
{
    public bool Sucesso { get; private set; } = false;

    public FormOpenDirectorySystem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sucesso = false;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void buttonContinuar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(loginSucedido)
            Sucesso = true;

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Na utilização

```
Form frm = new FormOpenDirectorySystem();
frm.ShowDialog();
bool sucesso = frm.Sucesso;
```

Comment: Visual Studio me retorna um erro dizendo que a propriedade que está no form secundário não existe, e ela está pública.

Comment: Dei Build no projeto, o erro persistiu .. Fechei e abri novamente o visual Studio, e agora o erro sumiu e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Eis então a solução, estava certo, mas o visual studio estava bugado e não me deixava compilar o programa ... Obrigado de qualquer forma!

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Para fazer é muito simples, poisbem, imagine que o formulario indicado por você seja uma classe ( e é realmente uma classe) e que esta classe também possui métodos (buttonContinuar_Click) e propriedades. Assim, nesta linha você deve apenas declarar uma propriedade publica nesta classe. Por exemplo:

```
public partial class FormOpenDirectorySystem : Form {
//Esse propriedade porderá ser acessar a partir da rotina chamadora
public bool ByPass { get;private set {value = bypass};}

public FormOpenDirectorySystem()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public bool bypass = false;
.
.
```

//A chamada seria ....

```
using(frm = new FormOpenDirectorySystem()){
   frm.ShowDialog();
var valorRetornado = frm.ByPass;
}
```