# Como posso pegar informação de um datagridview para utilizar em outra form

Tags: c#

Estou a fazer um programa em c# e tenho uma datagridview na `Form1` e tenho outra datagridview na `Form2`. Como posso pegar a celula selecionada  da datagridview que esta na `Form1` e utilizar na como variavel na `Form2`ou seja queria usar a variável `test` em outra `Form`

> Isto é como eu estou a ir pegar os valores das celulas na datagridview:

```
    if (dataGridViewEnviarDados.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridViewEnviarDados.SelectedRows)
     {
      string test = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()
     }
    }
```

Comment: @LINQ Eu não estou a intender o porque de a minha pergunta ser duplicada quando metade das respostas têm a ver com TextBoxs

Comment: Um controle é um controle. Tanto faz se é textbox ou combobox ou radiobutton ou qualquer coisa. Se eu bem entendi, você quer usar elementos de um form em outro form, isso já foi perguntado milhares de vezes aqui.

Comment: @LINQ Mas isso não ajuda no meu caso

Comment: Então seja mais específico e explique o problema detalhadamente. Com as informações que você deu, sua pergunta é duplicada. Quando editá-la, me mencione para que eu possa reabri-la se for o caso.

Comment: @LINQ já editei

Comment: Sua pergunta está respondida aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166563/passar-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-entre-forms-do-c

Comment: @LINQ Consegue dar um exemplo para a minha questão? Fiquei demasiado confuso com as respostas dadas nas perguntas que mencionou

Comment: A resposta selecionada (que por acaso foi eu mesmo quem escreveu) é o exemplo que vc precisa.

Comment: @LINQ Eu não estou intendendo a sua resposta desculpe... Eu fiquei um pouco confuso com a grande quantidade de exemplos que deu mas muito obrigado pela sua cooperação

Comment: Basicamente você vai fazer com que a variável `test` seja uma propriedade pública do form. Assim, poderá acessar de "fora"

Comment: Consegue fazer um exemplo com esse código para mim por favor

Comment: @LINQ Estive a ler novamente o exemplo que comentou e na minha opinião são características diferentes pois eu preciso de uma informação que esta na variável (test) da form1  para usar na form2 eu queria saber como posso meter a variável test a public mas definindo que ela vai ter o conteúdo da célula 2 da datagridview da form1 entendeu ?